# SQL2542N No match for a database image file was found based on the source database

Tags: db2, backup, restore

I'm trying to restore db and get such error

[db2inst1@db2server /]$ db2 restore database SOSDB from /tmp/restore/20210320 taken at 20210320122213 replace existing
SQL2542N  No match for a database image file was found based on the source
database alias "SOSDB" and timestamp "20210320122213" provided.

Run and get header
[db2inst1@db2server /]$ db2ckbkp -H /tmp/restore/20210320/122213.001

WARNING - Backup image from a release that is not supported.
Release ID -- 0xA00 (DB2 v8)

## =====================
MEDIA HEADER REACHED:

```
    Server Database Name           -- SOSDB
    Server Database Alias          -- SOSDB
    Client Database Alias          -- SOSDB
    Timestamp                      -- 20210320122213
    Database Partition Number      -- 0
    Instance                       -- DB2
    Database Configuration Type    -- 0 (Non-shared data)
    Sequence Number                -- 1
    Database Member ID             -- 0
    Release ID                     -- 0xA00 (DB2 v8)
    AL version                     -- V:0 R:0 M:0 F:0 I:0 SB:0
    Database Seed                  -- 0x3FC8552C
    DB Comment's Codepage (Volume) -- 0
    DB Comment (Volume)            --
    DB Comment's Codepage (System) -- 0
    DB Comment (System)            --
    Authentication Value           -- 255 (Not specified)
    Backup Mode                    -- 0 (Offline)
    Includes Logs                  -- 0 (No)
    Compression                    -- 0 (No Library Applied)
    Backup Type                    -- 0 (Database-level)
    Backup Granularity             -- 0 (Non-incremental)
    Merged Backup Image            -- 0 (No)
    Status Flags                   -- 0x11
                                      Consistent across all members
                                      LOGRETAIN is enabled for logging
    System Catalogs in this image  -- 1 (Yes)
    Catalog Partition Number       -- 0
    DB Codeset                     -- IBM-1252
    DB Territory                   --
    LogID                          -- 1616152010
    LogPath                        -- D:\soslogs\
    Backup Buffer Size             -- 6144000 (1500 4K pages)
    Number of Sessions             -- 1
    Platform                       -- 0x5 (NT-32)
    Encrypt Info Flags             -- 0x0
```

The proper image file name would be:
SOSDB.0.DB2.DBPART000.20210320122213.001

fill using header and get
[db2inst1@db2server /]$ db2 restore database SOSDB from /tmp/restore/20210320 taken at 20210320122213 replace existing
SQL2542N  No match for a database image file was found based on the source
database alias "SOSDB" and timestamp "20210320122213" provided.

Comment: It's not possible to restore from a backup taken on Windows to a Linux or Unix box even you had a db2 release supporting the v8 backup restoration. So, you must restore from this backup on Windows under v8 or v9.1 version, but not on Linux or Unix.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1):

I changed file name (I thought that database manager get metadata from header of the file but from name)

/tmp/restore/20210320/122213.001 -> /tmp/restore/20210320/SOSDB.0.DB2.DBPART000.20210320122213.001

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).